# How to check the svn server version

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I have configured a svn server to access via http using apache2. However when I execute the

```
svn --version
```

in the terminal it gives me

```
svn, version 1.8.8 (r1568071)
   compiled Sep 30 2014, 11:47:24 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Copyright (C) 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/
```

But when I access the repo in browser, it shows the version as follows.

```
Powered by Apache Subversion version 1.7.9 (r1462340).
```

How to determine the current svn server version correctly?

Comment: can you explain why there are two versions?..

Comment: Client version and server version. They don't need to be the same.

Comment: Apache modules are older, than CLI client-part